# Add qqline to normal qqplot for random forest model with lattice in r

Tags: r, random-forest, lattice, diagnostics, qq

I would like to use `lattice` R package to add qq-line to normal qq-plot for random forest model. I know there are ways to do this in `ggplot` and `plotly`, but I am interested in `lattice` this time.

```
data("cars")

library(randomForest)
library(lattice)

rf_model <- randomForest(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
residuals <- predict(rf_model, cars) - cars$speed

qqmath( ~ residuals, main = "Normal Q-Q plot", 
                     xlab = "Theorethical quantiles",
                     ylab = "Residuals")
```